# Bind a list to a ListBox from code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Im trying to bind a list to a ListBox but absolutely nothing happens. Im not getting any error but im sure the list that the ListBox binds to is populated cause i have a Text control that displays info showing there are three items in the collection.

So the question is what is required to bind to a ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbSlaves" Width="300" Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Slaves}" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
                <StackPanel Width="150" Height="30"  Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MachineName}"></TextBox>    <!-- Ive also tried Path=MachineName -->                   
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListBox>
```

Code behind

```
public List<ZTClient> Slaves { get; set; } 
     private void SetUpSlaves()
    {


        var client1 = new ZTClient()
        {
            MachineName = "Machine One",
            IpAdress = "34534512",
            Status = "Ready"
        };

        var client2 = new ZTClient()
        {
            MachineName = "Machine Two",
            IpAdress = "123456",
            Status = "Ready"
        };

        var client3 = new ZTClient()
        {
            MachineName = "Machine Three",
            IpAdress = "65464234",
            Status = "Ready"
        };

        AddClient(client1);
        AddClient(client2);
        AddClient(client3);

    //Ive also tried the following
    //lbSlaves.DataContext = Slaves;
        tbInfoBox.Text += "Nr of slaves = " + Slaves.Count() + Slaves[0].MachineName;

    }

    void SetInfoTex(string newText)
    {
        tbInfoBox.Text = newText;
    }

    private void AddClient(ZTClient newClient)
    {
        Slaves.Add(newClient);

    }
```

Comment: Check Output window for binding errors.

Comment: Use ObservableCellection for bound lists, if you change them later

Answer (score 0):

You bind a property (`TextBox.Text`) that binds `TwoWay` by default. Does your `MachineName` have a public setter?  If not change the binding mode to `OneWay` or rather make the setter more accessible to prevent binding errors.

You also update your info text manually but your `ListBox` bindings are not supported by change notifications, so they probably will not be synchronized. You should bind to an `ObservableCollection<ZTClient>`, and if you want to change the instances themselves, then the `ZTClient` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I havent tried your solution Yet but want to thank you for pointing out some aspects I didn't know about. I will read up on observable collection and different binding modes and what they require. Thanks!